# Subquery returns more rows than straight same query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to remove duplicates based on the combination of `listings.product_id` and `listings.channel_listing_id`

This simple query returns 400.000 rows (the id's of the rows I want to keep):

```
SELECT  id
    FROM  `listings`
    WHERE  is_verified = 0
    GROUP BY  product_id, channel_listing_id
```

While this variation returns 1.600.000 rows, which are all records on the table, not only is_verified = 0:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM (
        SELECT  id
            FROM  `listings`
            WHERE  is_verified = 0
            GROUP BY  product_id, channel_listing_id
         ) AS keepem
```

I'd expect them to return the same amount of rows.
What's the reason for this?  How can I avoid it (in order to use the subselect in the where condition of the DELETE statement)?

**EDIT:** I found that doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` in the outer `SELECT` "fixes" it (it returns 400.000 records as it should).  I'm still not sure if I should trust this subquery, for there is no `DISTINCT` in the `DELETE` statement.

**EDIT 2:** Seems to be just a bug in the way phpMyAdmin reports the total count of the rows.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query as it stands is ambiguous. Suppose you have two listings with the same product_id and channel_id. Then what `id` is supposed to be returned? The first, the second? Or both, ignoring the GROUP request?

What if there is **more than one id** with *different* product and channel ids?

Try removing the ambiguity by selecting `MAX(id) AS id` and adding DISTINCT.

Are there any foreign keys to worry about? If not, you could pour the original table into a copy, empty the original and copy back in it the non-duplicates only. Messier, but you only do SELECTs or DELETEs guaranteed to succeed, and you also get to keep a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Assign aliases in order to avoid field reference ambiguity:

```
SELECT 
    keepem.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        innerStat.id
    FROM
        `listings` AS innerStat
    WHERE
        innerStat.is_verified = 0
    GROUP BY
        innerStat.product_id,
        innerStat.channel_listing_id
) AS keepem
```